# Format capital letters at the start of a sentence

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, strings, .net

I have a set of predefined templates for messages, where you can insert different arguments to make it more specific.

In order for the messages to be looking good I needed a way to capitalize the first letters of each sentence because you might pass the argument fully lower-cased while in some messages that argument happen to be the start of the sentence which would require a capital letter at the start.

This is my extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static readonly char[] _punctuationMarks = {'.', '!', '?'};

    public static string FormatCapitalLetters(this string source)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        result.Append(source.First().ToUpper());
        for (int i = 1; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            result.Append(source[i]);
            if (IsPunctuationMark(source[i]))
            {
                int index = i + 1;
                if (index >= source.Length || IsPunctuationMark(source[index]))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (source[index] == ' ')
                {
                    index++;
                }
                result.Append(' ');
                result.Append(source[index].ToUpper());
                i += index - i;
            }
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }

    private static string ToUpper(this char input) => input.ToString().ToUpper();

    private static bool IsPunctuationMark(char input) => _punctuationMarks.Any(
        punctuationMark => punctuationMark == input);
}
```

I'm looking for any comments on how to improve the current code or fix any flaws I'm unaware of, any alternative solutions are welcome as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Multispace bug

There is one flaw in this solution. It assumes a perfectly formatted sentence. This means that if there are multiple spaces between sentences the formatting won't work. For example it turns this `"foo.  bar!    baz?"` into `"Foo.  bar!    baz?"`

To fix this you either need another extension fixing all multiple spaces with a single one or make this one aware of this problem.

> ```
> if (source[index] == ' ')
> {
>   index++;
> }
> ```

This `if` should contain a `continue` but even with it, it won't work yet because the first `if` won't pass the second time. The logic is more complex and it would require a flag to skip "" spaces.

---

## Trim

> ```
> result.Append(source.First().ToUpper());
> ```

You assume that the first char is the first letter but you don't trim the `source` in case it isn't.

---

## Naming

> ```
> if (IsPunctuationMark(source[i]))
> {
>     int index = i + 1;
>     if (index >= source.Length || IsPunctuationMark(source[index]))
>     {
>         continue;
>     }
>     if (source[index] == ' ')
>     {
>         index++;
>     }
>     result.Append(' ');
>     result.Append(source[index].ToUpper());
>     i += index - i;
> }
> ```

Here I find the `index` too general. It looks like it should be called e.g. `firstLetterIndex`.

## Alternative? ;-)

You could use regex to clean-up the string.

```
public static string CapitalizeSentence(this string source)
{
    return 
        Regex
            .Replace(
                source.Trim(), 
                @"(^|(?<Punctuation>[.!?])\s*)(?<FirstLetter>[a-z])", 
                m => 
                    $"{(m.Groups["Punctuation"].Success ? m.Groups["Punctuation"].Value + " " : string.Empty)}" +
                    $"{m.Groups["FirstLetter"].Value.ToUpper()}");      
}
```

Comment: +1 As someone who avoids Regex like plague (read: can't be bothered to learn them) and loathes string interpolation, that alternative is just horrifying! (Thanks for putting me onto [this overload of Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx), very clean indeed)

Comment: @VisualMelon it's not a good idea to avoid anything but use everything responsibly ;-) it's there to make your life easier (where appropriate). There's even a place für `goto`.

Comment: Quite, I suppose I've just seen enough genuinely terrifying regex in my time (the not-regular variety) to put me off them rather! Ja, `goto` certainly has sensible uses, and I don't hesitate when I see one. You'll have to work hard to convince me string interpolation was a valuable addition to C#, though, I'm sceptical of all these little features which can trip up new users (C# is _easy_ and that is my favourite feature of it (aside from the sensible type system))